# How to handle 'record does not exist' errors and prevent background jobs from attempting retries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rails-activejob

A Rails app has a background job that calls a service object as below

```
class ObjectUpdateJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(object_id)
    ObjectUpdater.call(object_id)
  end
end

class ObjectUpdater

  def self.call(*args)
    if @object = Object.find( args[:object_id] )
      #... update some stuff from external services 
    else 
      #... raise an error and prevent the background job from attempting to retry
    end
  end
end
```

This may be a simple question, but my experience with error handling is limited and I'd appreciate a second thought on this.

What is the 'Rails way' of handling this 'record does not exist' case, and ensuring the background job is informed so that no retries are attempted?

Comment: You can easily and rails way handle the exception as http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#exceptions . But not idea, about the preventing job retry. I am not seeing any docs for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put a guard clause into worker's `perform` action:

```
class ObjectUpdateJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(object_id)
    return unless Object.find(object_id)
    ObjectUpdater.call(object_id)
  end
end
```

But for more protection you can put some check to the job call:

```
ObjectUpdateJob.perform_now(object_id) if Object.find(object_id)
```

This way you just won't let the inexistent object to be processed.

Comment: The object may be deleted after queueing, so better to have both checks

Comment: Thanks @AndreyDeineko, this is useful. Appreciate if you can answer a few questions to help me understand this a little more. (1) What are the pros/cons of calling `fail ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 'string'` vs `fail 'string'` in this case? (2) You are suggesting to call a service object, that launches a background job, that calls a service object. Is this common - I'm concerned it may add confusion to the code? (3) I've not come across `= Struct.new(:id)` before. It appears to replace an `initialize` method. Is this correct, and can you point towards any docs? Thanks!

Comment: @AndyHarvey 1) not sure of any, for me it was always enough to just `fail`.. 2) You're right, my mistake - have no idea what was I thinking about. You're absolutely right, do not do so. But the idea of it is simple, just make a guard clause in the place, where you call the worker, like `ObjectUpdateJob .perform_now(object_id) if Object.find(object_id)`. This + having the return statement in the `perform` should be enough to not process inexistent record. 3) Yeap, [Struct](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Struct.html) is very useful thing for such things, as service objects, for example.

Comment: Another option is to override the `ActiveJob::Core`s `initialize` method, putting the `fail` there. You could consider that, but you know, patching Rails does not seem to be a super clean solution

Comment: @AndyHarvey let me know, if I can help you further

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sidekiq you can set a flag to `:retry => false` so that jobs do not retry automatically.

Additionally Sidekiq has built in error handling mechanism. Here is more information regarding the matter: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @rii, what I'm really looking for is a way to prevent retires under very specific circumstances, rather than globally. e.g, something like `sidekiq_options :retry => false unless Object.find( args[:object_id] )`. Any ideas?